# I am trying to create a code that is able to calculate what grade a person needs to get on a test in order to get their ideal overall grade

Tags: python

I was having problems with my equation, and the accuracy of the output after you input a certain value

```
Ideal= int(input("What grade do you want on your next assignment?"))

Current= int(input("What is your current grade in the class?"))
weight =  int(input("how much of your grade is the assignment worth?")) 

weight=float(weight)/100

print weight


Final_grade = Ideal - (( 1 - weight ) * Current) / weight

if Final_grade <0:
    print "You would have to get a negative grade to get that number, which is impossible" 
elif Final_grade>0:
    print "You will need to get a" ,round(Final_grade,2)  ,"%", "on your next assignment to recieve a" , Ideal ,"%" "in this class"
else:
    print "number is invalid"
```

Comment: Hi Sid, welcome on SO. Please format your code and have a look at [how-to-ask](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: So you were having problems. And what are those problems? Did you try to solve them?

Comment: Welcome Sid, What kind of problems are you facing in this code? be specific.

Comment: If you're using Python 2.x, as it appears from your `print` statements, you should use `raw_input()` to read input.

Comment: I was having problems with how to make the output of my code accurate.. for example, if you typed in that your grade that you want is 100, the grade that you have currently is 50, and the weight of the code is 30, the answer should be that you would need 216.67 % to get a 100 in this class, but instead it triggers my if statement and says that it would be a negative answer.

Comment: Take a look at PEP8... Your code needs some formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bracket in wrong place in your expression:

```
Final_grade = Ideal - (( 1 - weight ) * Current) / weight
```

should be

```
Final_grade = (Ideal - ( 1 - weight ) * Current) / weight
```

This is from rearranging the following equation (note that the following is an algebraic equation, not a line of code):

Ideal = weight * Final_grade + (1-weight) * current